# Suppose that $H_1/H_2$ is Abelian. Show that $H_1 N / H_2 N$ is Abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H_1$, $H_2$, $N$ are subgroups of $G$. $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $H_2$ is a normal subgroup of $H_1$. Suppose that $H_1/H_2$ is Abelian. Show that $H_1N/H_2N$ is Abelian.

My current thought is using third isomorphism theorem and deduct $H_1N/H_2N$ is a quotient of $H_1/H_2$. However, I just cannot prove $H_1N/H_2N$ is a quotient of $H_1/H_2$. Does my thought wrong?

Comment: Consider the map $H_1\to H_1N/H_2N$ defined by $h\mapsto \langle h e\rangle$. This is a surjective homomorphism whose kernel contains $H_2$...

Answer (score 1):

This can be proven using only the definition of the quotient. Suppose $H_1/H_2$ is abelian, then for any $a,b \in H_1$ we have $aba^{-1}b^{-1} =h \in H_2$. Now let $an,bm\in H_1N$ be given. We have $$\begin{align} anbmn^{-1}a^{-1}m^{-1}b^{-1} & = an(a^{-1}a)bmn^{-1}a^{-1}(b^{-1}b)m^{-1}b^{-1}\\
& = n'abmn^{-1}a^{-1}b^{-1}m'\\
& = n'abmn^{-1}[(ab)^{-1}(ab)]a^{-1}b^{-1}m'\\
& = n'm''aba^{-1}b^{-1}m'\\ & = n'm''hm'
\end{align} $$ where $n',m',m'' \in N$ and their existence follows from normality of $N$.  As $n'm''hm'\in H_2N$ by definition, we have $anbm(bman)^{-1} \in H_2N$ hence $H_1N/H_2N$ is abelian.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good. After you have proved that $H_2N$ is a normal subgroup of $H_1N$, you can consider the map
$$
H_1\to H_1N/H_2N,\qquad x\mapsto xH_2N
$$
Prove this map is a surjective homomorphism. The kernel is $H_1\cap H_2N$. Since $H_1\cap H_2N\supseteq H_2$, …

Answer (score 0):

A proof using the second and third isomorphism theorems goes like this
$$
\frac{H_{1} N}{H_{2} N}
=
\frac{H_{1} H_{2}  N}{H_{2} N}
\cong
\frac{H_{1}}{H_{1} \cap H_{2} N}
\cong
\frac{H_{1} / H_{2}}{(H_{1} \cap H_{2} N) / H_{2}},
$$
and the latter is abelian, as an homomorphic image of the abelian group $H_{1}/H_{2}$. (Note that $H_{2}$ is indeed contained in $H_{1} \cap H_{2} N$.)